# Typing in Sinhala

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I am trying to use the fontspec package and gnu-freefonts to type in Sinhala.  I have seen an example in the link [Old ligatures in Siṇhala](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175441/old-ligatures-in-si%E1%B9%87hala).

So my first attempt is to use the above example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\setmainfont[Language=Sinhala]{Bhashita.ttf}

\begin{document}
සිංහල.
\end{document}
```

That does not work.  I have a relatively new mac (2015) and I have seen reports of font installation problems with newer Mac OS's. (I have Yosemite.) Therefore, I placed the font in a specific folder and included the path in the next try.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
%\setmainfont[Language=Sinhala]{Bhashita.ttf}
\setmainfont[Language=Sinhala, 
    Path=/Users/myName/Documents/Exported Fonts/]{Bhashitha.ttf}

\begin{document}
සිංහල.
\end{document}
```

That does not work either.

Then I have seen the following example on the web. [Preparing Latex Documents in Sinhala (සිංහල) Language](http://recolog.blogspot.com/2016/08/preparing-latex-documents-in-sinhala.html).

Even though TeX Live Utility indicates that gnu-freefonts are installed in my computer, the TeX compiler is not finding them.

(1) Is it possible to get any of these methods to work?

(2) Is there a solution to font installation problem (in Mac) in general?

[New addition to my original post]
The following code produces an output, even though the output is not rendered correctly.  I am really confused now.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\setmainfont\[Language=Sinhala, 
    Path=/Users/MyName/Documents/Exported Fonts/]{Bhashitha}

\title{සිංහල අකුරු}
\author{සැලෙන මනස විසිනි}
\date{}                                           
\begin{document}
\maketitle
මේ වාර්තාව පිලියෙල කලේ XeLaTeX භාවිතා කරමිනි. මෙහි අකුරු පැබැඳුම 
සඳහා ගිශාන් ගේ SinhalaInput භාවිතා කල අතර,  අකුරු ලබා ගත්තේ හී 
Bhashitha මගිනි. මේ සිංහල අකුරු ICTA විසින් නිර්මානය කරන ලද්දකි.
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the last example.]

Comment: Yes. I will fix it in the post.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the output of the third code sample.  Therefore, it must be a fluke.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I placed my font file in the same directory as the Tex file and ran your third example code with xelatex. My machine is a 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with TexLive Full package installation. It worked with only a small glitch as you can see from the screenshot.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\setmainfont[Language=Sinhala]{LBhashitaComplex.ttf}

\title{සිංහල අකුරු}
\author{සැලෙන මනස විසිනි}
\date{}                                           

\begin{document}
\maketitle
මේ වාර්තාව පිලියෙල කලේ XeLaTeX භාවිතා කරමිනි. මෙහි අකුරු පැබැඳුම 
සඳහා ගිශාන් ගේ SinhalaInput භාවිතා කල අතර,  අකුරු ලබා ගත්තේ හී 
Bhashitha මගිනි. මේ සිංහල අකුරු ICTA විසින් නිර්මානය කරන ලද්දකි.
\end{document}
```

The command I used to run above Latex file from the terminal

```
xelatex my-example.tex
```

Here's the output:
[image]

Comment: Everything seems fine except the A in ICTA.  (Tried on OSX Yosemite with TexLive)

Comment: I am still getting the output that I posted for the third example.  Can this be a Mac OS Yosemite problem?

Comment: It is an "ispilli" and "papilli" problem.  They are not rendered properly.

Comment: If Chamod says he got the same output as me on a Mac OS Yosemite, I guess it's a problem with the TexLive package you have installed. Can you try to install the latest "texlive-full" package and try to run the code once again?

Answer (score 2):

Things have changed since I asked this question.  The solution provided by asanka.code using BhashithaComplex font worked except for the missing "A" in ICTA.

I have experimented with several fonts, namely; iskpota, Sinhala Sangam MN, macbashitha, and again with BahashithaComplex.  The best font to use at the moment is iskpota.ttf.  The following is the code and the output.  I will accept asanka.code's answer.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setmainfont{iskpota.ttf}
%\setmainfont{Sinhala Sangam MN}
%\setmainfont{BhashitaComplex.ttf}
%\setmainfont{macbashitha.ttf}

\title{සිංහල අකුරු}
\author{සැලෙන මනස විසිනි}
\date{}                                           
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent මේ වාර්තාව පිලියෙල කලේ XeLaTeX භාවිතා කරමිනි. මෙහි අකුරු පැබැඳුම 
සඳහා ගිශාන් ගේ SinhalaInput භාවිතා කල අතර,  අකුරු ලබා ගත්තේ හී 
Bhashitha මගිනි. මේ සිංහල අකුරු ICTA විසින් නිර්මානය කරන ලද්දකි.
\end{document}
```

[image]